# How to I consume nested data structures returned from Redux without running into errors such as 'cannot access property x of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm trying to use Redux selectors to extract specific data from nested data structures returned from the Redux store.

```
const getContactPhone = state => (state.home.data.blocks[1].contactPhone);
```

I'm getting this data from an API and storing it in the store when my Next.js site loads using `getInitialProps`.  It seems that the store data appears and disappears -- perhaps this has something to do with the way Next.js and next-redux-wrapper handle store creation.  In any case I kept getting 'cannot read contactPhone of undefined' errors, for example.

Obviously I can put checks in such as

```
const getContactPhone = state => (state && state.home && state.home.data 
 && state.home.data.blocks && state.home.data.blocks[1] ? state.home.data.blocks[1].contactPhone : '');
```

But that seems awkward and ugly.  Is there a better way to handle this?  Is there some library that will help me?

Thanks for any clues on the way forward!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda has a [`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) function. You pass the path to the property as an array of strings. If the property exists, its value is returned; otherwise it returns `undefined`.

```js
console.log(R.path(['a', 'b', 'c', 0], { a: { b: { c: [1, 2] } } })); // 1
console.log(R.path(['a', 'b', 'c', 0], {})); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```